# SwiftUI CloudKit Public Database with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

Based on WWDC20 talk bellow:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10650/

The way to setup CloudKit Public Database with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer in "one line of code" is this:

```
    description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey:NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
    description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
```

[image]

How would that be on the new SwiftUI Persistent.swift template?

I tried the code bellow but didn't work:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
    
   //This doesnt work
    //container.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public


    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Market")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                Typical reasons for an error here include:
                * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                * The device is out of space.
                * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
     print("Can't set description")
     fatalError("Error")
 }
    
 description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
```